# Error 403(forbidden) ng-file-upload

Tags: angularjs, ng-file-upload

I am new with angularjs, why I am getting error 403 forbidden?
The directory in the server has got all the permissions.
Error:
angular.js:10765 GET http://....../ 403 (Forbidden)

Controller:

```
$scope.submit = function() {
   if ($scope.form.file.$valid && $scope.file) {
     console.log($scope.file);
     $scope.save($scope.file);
   }
 };

$scope.save = function (file) {
      console.log('conferma');
      Upload.upload({
        url: '/uix/circolari/uploadCircolari',
        data: {file: file}
      }).then(function (resp) {
        console.log('Success ' + resp.config.data.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + resp.data);
      }, function (resp) {
        console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
      }, function (evt) {
        var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
        console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name);
      });
    };
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Who is handling requests to `/uix/circolari/uploadCircolari` - what server is it? Share the code or config of that, the issue you have has nothing to do with angularjs

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have just resolved my problem :)

Comment: @SimoneBrunori I know its too late. Can you provide more info how you resolved the problem.